# R is not connecting to HDFS

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, java-6, rhadoop

**Why is R not connecting to Hadoop ?**

I am using R to connect to HDFS using 'rhdfs' package. The 'rJava' package is installed and rhdfs package is loaded.

The HADOOP_CMD environment variable is set in R using:

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD='/usr/local/hadoop/bin')
```

But when hdfs.init() function is given, the following error message is generated:

```
sh: 1: /usr/local/hadoop/bin: Permission denied
Error in .jnew("org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration") : 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
In addition: Warning message:
running command '/usr/local/hadoop/bin classpath' had status 126
```

Also, 'rmr2' library was loaded, and the following code was typed:

```
ints = to.dfs(1:100)
```

which generated the message given below:

```
sh: 1: /usr/local/hadoop/bin: Permission denied
```

The R-Hadoop packages are accessible only to the 'root' user and not 'hduser' (Hadoop user), since they were installed when R was run by the 'root' user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this.

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD='/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop')

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64')

library(rhdfs)

hdfs.init()

please give the correct HADOOP_CMD path  extend with   /bin/hadoop
```

Comment: When `library(rmr2)` is given, it gives a warning:   `Please review your hadoop settings. See help(hadoop.settings)
Warning message:
S3 methods ‘gorder.default’, ‘gorder.factor’, ‘gorder.data.frame’, ‘gorder.matrix’, ‘gorder.raw’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found`. Could you tell me why ?

Answer (score 2):

Simple, only 2 reasons to get this type of problem

1) Wrong path
2) No privileges/permissions to that jar ok
not only that include other system paths. such as given below.

```
Sys.setenv(HADOOP_HOME="/home/hadoop/path")

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_CMD="/home/hadoop/path/bin/hadoop")

Sys.setenv(HADOOP_STREAMING="/home/hadoop/path/streaming-jar-file.jar")

Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="/home/hadoop/java/path")
```

Then include ibrary(rmr2) and library(rhdfs) paths, surely that error don't occur.

But your problem is Permission problem. So as a root grant all privileges (755) to you then run that jar file, surely that error don't display.